# How can we set log tracer after we deploy application in server

Tags: spring-boot

I think it's simple question but I did not get proper answer and may be my knowledge on spring boot some what less

So please kindly help me how can I trace my application logs after we deploy our application in production or development server

Comment: It depends on your logback (or other log tool) configurations. Please extend your answer with info on what you already have: are your logs simply printed to the console, what is your log level, etc.

Comment: I am asking after we deployed war in production server if there is any errors will occur how can we identify them?

Comment: So as I understand you have not configured you logging anyhow so far?

Comment: Yes, how can I do this ?

Comment: 83.1.1 Configure Logback for File-only Output here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-logging.html . There are complex strategies of log files configuration, but for now try at least configuring an appender so that you logs got printed to file.

Make sure your `logback.xml` is in `resources` directory